# Update JSON with jQuery & PHP - json_decode() returning empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to post json to a txt file but having some problems with my data. Whenever I check my data to be sent in jQuery it all looks fine, but if I print it out in php I see escape slashes and json_decode returns that data as empty. Here's the snippets of code:

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'update-json.php',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : {json : JSON.stringify([{'name':'Bob'},{'name':'Tom'}])},
    success : function(){
        console.log('success');
    },
    error : function(){
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $json = $_POST['json'];
    $entries = json_decode($json);

    $file = fopen('data-out.txt','w');
    fwrite($file, $entries);
    fclose($file);
?>
```

**PHP ECHO $json**

```
[{\"name\":\"Bob\"},{\"name\":\"Tom\"}]
```

**PHP ECHO $entries**

```
//EMPTY
```

Comment: From the docs for `json_decode()`: *`NULL` is returned if the json cannot be decoded*.

Comment: Yea - I assume because of the extra slashes being added it can't decode it. I guess the real question is how to fix those quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have magic_quotes turned on in PHP. Generally you should turn this off to avoid problems like this. If you can't do that you need to call `stripslashes()` on your incoming string.

You can also check `json_last_error()` to find out why it couldn't decode.

Edit: Here's how you put in `stripslashes`

```
$json = stripslashes($_POST['json']);
$entries = json_decode($json);

if( !$entries ) {
     $error = json_last_error();
     // check the manual to match up the error to one of the constants
}
else {

    $file = fopen('data-out.txt','w');
    fwrite($file, $json);
    fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: I tried `$entries = stripslashes(json_decode($json));` but it writes `[{\"name\":\"Bob\"},{\"name\":\"Tom\"}]` to the txt file. Is there a way to not show those slashes?

Comment: You need to call `stripslashes` before you call `json_decode`. That code calls `json_decode` first

Comment: Thanks - I tried that but now it just writes `Array` to the file.

Comment: I missed that you're printing `$json` to the file instead of `$entries` (in the code above). Is that your intent? If you just write `$entries` to the file I would expect it to say Array. What is the final result you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: also you can verify that you have data from entries by doing `print_r($entries)`

Comment: Trying to write the json. I updated my question to show $entries. I'd like to see the text file contain: `[{'name':'Bob'},{'name':'Tom'}]`

Comment: Ahh genius - thanks! I was doing too much work apparently, lol.